# Jackson custom serializer json format

Tags: json

I want to make my serialized json look like this:

```
{
 "abc": "smth",
 "def": "smth",
 "ghi": "smth",
}
```

How can I achieve this with jackson? Here is what I've done so far

```
@Override
    public void serialize(Value value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        gen.writeStringField("abc", value.getAaa());
        gen.writeStringField("def", value.getDdd());
        gen.writeStringField("ghi", value.getGgg());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
```

and I get following output

```
{
"abc" : "smth",
"def" : "smth",
"ghi" : "smth",
}
```

Comment: you want to pretty-print that json, right ?

Comment: Hmm, yea - I didn't know that is has a name :)

Comment: then you couldn't find [that page...](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html#setPrettyPrinter(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.PrettyPrinter))

Comment: Thats what I've done - look at my code. The output is not satysfying for me

Comment: yeah I was going to remove my comment... Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand you want to see indents before fields in object. So, to achieve this just swap two lines:

```
gen.useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
gen.writeStartObject();
...
```

My test application:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();

        JsonGenerator gen = jsonFactory.createGenerator(System.out);

        gen.useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("abc", "1");
        gen.writeStringField("def", "2");
        gen.writeStringField("ghi", "3");
        gen.writeEndObject();

        gen.flush();
    }
}
```

generate the following output:

```
{
  "abc" : "1",
  "def" : "2",
  "ghi" : "3"
}
```

**Update**: About spaces around `:`. Look at [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/1656a115d64afb893f50d15f9ec744524368b93b/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter.java#L280) method. As you can see it is has only two options: `<space>:<space>` and `:` So, out of the box you can't do it but you can override this method:

```
gen.setPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter() {
    @Override
    public void writeObjectFieldValueSeparator(JsonGenerator jg) throws IOException {
        jg.writeRaw(": ");
    }
});
```

and use custom pretty printer instead of `useDefaultPrettyPrinter`. In this case the output will be:

```
{
  "abc": "1",
  "def": "2",
  "ghi": "3"
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! Is it possible to omit spaces before colon? Like in my first post

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Look at **Update** section.

Comment: Thanks, that helps for me! Also, by using ": " separator, it can be matched with python json.dumps()

Answer (score 9):

To override `writeObjectFieldValueSeparator()` function you also need to override `createInstance` method to.

This worked for me:

```
public class MyPrettyPrinter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter {

    @Override
    public DefaultPrettyPrinter createInstance() {
        return new MyPrettyPrinter();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeObjectFieldValueSeparator(JsonGenerator jg) throws IOException {
        jg.writeRaw(": ");
    }

}
```

Then just use it as writer of your mapper:

```
objectMapper.writer(new MyPrettyPrinter()).writeValueAsString(object);
```

You can find more information about this issue [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/199).

Comment: Note: if you directly set `_objectFieldValueSeparatorWithSpaces = ": "` in your subclass's initializer (it's a protected field), you won't have to override `createInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

Add Indentation feature to mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
   String indent= mapper.writeValueAsString(valueObject);
```

Comment: This doesn't fixe the issue. Some environments generate with white space before colon, and others don't.