# How to use indentation in gson to generate a json file

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to generate a `json` file containing indentation. I was using `Jackson` for this but it adds a space before the colon and I don't need it, so I decided to use `Gson`.

After changing the code, I figured out that by default `Gson` don't use indentation but `Jackson` does. Does anyone know if it is possible in `Gson` to get indentation and how to do it?

For generating the `json` file with `Gson` I made this:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Writer writer = new FileWriter(propsFile); 
gson.toJson(properties, writer);
```

Comment: If there is any solution to change the default intent in Gson, I can use Jackson, but how  I eliminate the space before colon?

Comment: What do you mean by "use `Intent`"?

Comment: I believe he/she means "indent"

Comment: Edited question and retagged as appropriate.

Comment: I meant "indent" indeed. Do you have some suggestions about how I could solve it?

Comment: You should post a small example of what you want your JSON to look like, because setting pretty print on is supposed to make JSON readable already, but it seems you don't like that format.

Answer (score 2):

You can only employ the default indentation provided by `setPrettyPrinting()` and you cannot change its size or indentation characters. Please refer to the official information about it: [Compact Vs. Pretty Printing for JSON Output Format](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Compact-Vs.-Pretty-Printing-for-JSON-Output-Format).

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41509714/4379906

---

Use Jackson and and configure it not to add spaces before colon:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

`CustomPrettyPrinter.java`:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter;

import java.io.IOException;

class CustomPrettyPrinter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter {
    public CustomPrettyPrinter() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomPrettyPrinter(DefaultPrettyPrinter base) {
        super(base);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeObjectFieldValueSeparator(JsonGenerator g) throws IOException {
        g.writeRaw(": ");
    }

    @Override
    public DefaultPrettyPrinter createInstance() {
        return new CustomPrettyPrinter(this);
    }
}
```

`UseJackson.java`:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class UseJackson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DefaultPrettyPrinter.Indenter indenter = new DefaultIndenter("    ", DefaultIndenter.SYS_LF);
        DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new CustomPrettyPrinter();
        printer.indentArraysWith(indenter);
        printer.indentObjectsWith(indenter);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setDefaultPrettyPrinter(printer);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("foo", "3");
        properties.put("bar", "4");
        objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new File("a.json"), properties);
    }
}
```

---

Use Gson and configure indentation:

`UseGson.java`:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class UseGson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("foo", "3");
        properties.put("bar", "4");

        JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter("a.json"));
        jsonWriter.setIndent("    ");

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        gson.toJson(properties, Properties.class, jsonWriter);

        jsonWriter.close();
    }
}
```