# Remove trailing whitespace from JSON key output with Jackson Deserialized POJO in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

In Springboot I have a class that is converting a POJO to a JSON file

```
public class GoogleJSONAuthWriter {

public void writeGoogleAuthPropertiesToJSON(GoogleAuthProperties googleAuthProperties) throws IOException {

    // create object mapper instance
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // convert map to JSON file
    mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(Paths.get("key.json").toFile(), googleAuthProperties);

}

}
```

It is producing this file:

```
{
  "type" : "service_account",
  "project_id" : "secret-walker-355609",
}
```

I need it to produce this format file:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "secret-walker-355609",
}
```

So I need to remove the single space after each key but retain the single space on the other side of the ':'

Is there a pain free way to do this or do I need to write a custom deserializer? I have no experience of doing the latter so if that is the case how should I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson custom serializer json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508864/jackson-custom-serializer-json-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the best way with Jackson is to override the DefaulPrettyPrinter.

You will need at minimum Jackson version 2.9

```
public class ExtendedPrettyPrinter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter {

  public ExtendedPrettyPrinter() {
    _objectFieldValueSeparatorWithSpaces = ": ";
  }

  private ExtendedPrettyPrinter(ExtendedPrettyPrinter extendedPrettyPrinter) 
 {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public DefaultPrettyPrinter createInstance() {
    return new ExtendedPrettyPrinter(this);
  }
}
```

The following is how to use the new pretty printer

```
mapper.writer(new ExtendedPrettyPrinter()).writeValue(Paths.get("key.json").toFile(), googleAuthProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-json/gson.html

Specifically

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

Got me the Google format json I was looking for