# How to remove spaces between "key" and a ":" during serialization using Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, nsjsonserialization

I'm using Jackson library for serialization. To indent the output I have the following code

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);`

This results in adding spaces that I don't need. For example,

```
{
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "theUser"
}
```

I want my output to be

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "theUser"
}
```

Basically, I want space between key and : to be removed. Is there a easy way to get rid of this additional space?

Answer (score 2):

Although Ivar provided the answer [already in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508864/jackson-custom-serializer-json-format), here's my implementation of it, which returns your desired result.

```
DefaultPrettyPrinter pp = new MyPrettyPrinter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);;
        try {
            jsonResult = mapper.writer(pp)
                    .writeValueAsString(map);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

where MyPrettyPrinter is the following:

```
public class MyPrettyPrinter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter {

@Override
public DefaultPrettyPrinter createInstance() {
    return new MyPrettyPrinter();
}

@Override
public void writeObjectFieldValueSeparator(JsonGenerator jg) throws IOException {
    jg.writeRaw(": ");
}
```

}